# JavaScript object value update on input-event

Tags: javascript, constants

So far, the following code does not update the value of `email.value.length` of the `errorMessages` constant. The idea is to display the remaining qty of characters to return true;

Thanks in advance;

```js
const email = document.getElementById("mce-EMAIL");

const errorMessages = {
  typeMismatch: 'I am expecting an e-mail address!',
  valueMissing: 'You need to enter an e-mail address',
  tooShort: `Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }`
};

function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
  return errorMessages[errorMessage];
}

const typeCheck = (onValue) => {
  let typeMismatch, valueMissing, tooShort;
  
  typeMismatch = (onValue.validity.typeMismatch) ? displayErrorMessage('typeMismatch') : true;
  valueMissing = (onValue.validity.valueMissing) ? displayErrorMessage('valueMissing') : true;
  tooShort = (onValue.validity.tooShort) ? displayErrorMessage('tooShort') : true;
  
  return false;
}

email.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  typeCheck(event.explicitOriginalTarget);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to find out what you expect if you would provide your html. ;o)

What it looks like: you defined your `const errorMessages` initially in your function. That means it never upddates the values in it.

Put your const in the `displayErrorMessage()` function and it will work.

```
function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
    const errorMessages = {
        typeMismatch: 'I am expecting an e-mail address!',
        valueMissing: 'You need to enter an e-mail address',
        tooShort: `Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }`
    };
    return errorMessages[errorMessage];
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const email = document.getElementById("mce-EMAIL");
const output = document.getElementById("output");


function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {

const errorMessages = {
  typeMismatch: 'I am expecting an e-mail address!',
  valueMissing: 'You need to enter an e-mail address',
  tooShort: `Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }`
};

output.innerHTML = errorMessages[errorMessage];

  return errorMessages[errorMessage];
}

const typeCheck = (onValue) => {
  let typeMismatch, valueMissing, tooShort;
  
  typeMismatch = (onValue.validity.typeMismatch) ? displayErrorMessage('typeMismatch') : true;
  valueMissing = (onValue.validity.valueMissing) ? displayErrorMessage('valueMissing') : true;
  tooShort = (onValue.validity.tooShort) ? displayErrorMessage('tooShort') : true;
  
  return false;
}

email.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  typeCheck(event.explicitOriginalTarget);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="email" id="mce-EMAIL" minlength="10">
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```